# Inner product and distance

Tags: real-analysis, inner-products

My question is this, is there a proof to show that suppose the distance $||h(x)- g(x)||< 4$, then $|h(x) - g(x) | <4$ for all $x\in [-\pi, \pi]$? I know from Schwarz inequality that $$|h - g| \leq ||h- g||.$$

Note that the inner product space $PC [-\pi , \pi]$ the distance between two functions is $$ ||h-g||^2= \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} |h(x) - g(x) |^{2} dx.$$
I hope I can just state that and there will not be anything to prove.

Comment: What does $|h-g|$ mean?

Comment: What is $|h-g|$ and what is $\lVert h-g\rVert$?

Comment: I think what OP means is suppose that $\|h-g\| < 4$, then for all $x$ in the domain of $g$ and $h$ (which I can guess here is $[-\pi,\pi]$), then $|h(x) - g(x)| < 4$. But we'll obviously need OP to confirm that.

Comment: Thanks but what I meant was  suppose that$ ||h−g||<4 $, then for all $x$ in the domain of g and h  in ([−π,π]), then $|h(x)−g(x)|<4 $.

Comment: @Beat: Assuming that that comment was intended to refer to my answer: Yes, that's how I understood your question, and that's what I answered. This is false for the reasons I pointed out.

Answer (score 1):

No, this is not the case. Given your definition of the distance between two functions, the function values can be arbitrarily far apart if this occurs in a sufficiently small region. For instance, consider $g(x)=0$ and $h(x)$ a rectangular pulse that can be arbitrarily high as long as it is sufficiently short.